# Mathjax automatic linebreak when opened in a modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, mathjax, sweetalert2

For a math project, the solution of a problem should be displayed in a Sweetalert2 modal. Unfortunately although using

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config"> 
MathJax.Hub.Config({
tex2jax: {
     inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]
},
"HTML-CSS": { 
     linebreaks: { automatic: true }
},
SVG: { 
     linebreaks: { automatic: true } 
}
}); 
</script>
```

the automatic line break is not working in a Sweetalert2 modal (see image). Is there any fix for that.

With best greeting, Leon

[image: problematic image]

Comment: Please post a live sample.

Comment: Could the following `CSS` property helps: `word-break: break-all;` ?

Comment: Here comes the sample: https://jsfiddle.net/6g07reba/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code is rendered in different from HTML-CSS and SVG processor (most likely a `Common HTML`). Try adding more configs, like:

```
CommonHTML: { 
  linebreaks: { automatic: true }
}, 
PreviewHTML: { 
  linebreaks: { automatic: true }
}
```

**EDIT**

You are also able to specify the output processor by hand with

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End Jax", function () {
 return MathJax.Hub.setRenderer("HTML-CSS");
});
```

You can check more possibilities to determining right processor [here](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/output.html#automatic-selection-of-the-output-processor)